# Binding TextBox to ObservableCollection.Count WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `TextBox` with the text bound to the count of an `ObervableCollection` which shows the users how many rows are displayed in a UI `DataGrid` which is bound to the same collection.

```
Text="{Binding ModelviewArticleObservableList.Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This works great. However, I have a `ClearButton` which is bound to a `Command` the command method clears the `ObservableCollection` and reads in new values. The Count on my `TextBox` is causing big memory problems, presumably because it's trying to iterate over the collection as the values are being read in.

This isn't a problem on application load as the `viewModel` is instantiated in the `constructor` before `InitializeComponent()` when the count takes place in the view (ViewModel first). The memory issue is just when the `ClearButton` command is invoked.

Is there any way to sleep the binding or something so the `Count` method is invoked after the `ObservableCollection` is compiled?

Here is my `ObservableCollection` property in my view model:

```
    private ObservableCollection<viewArticle> _ModelviewArticleObservableList = new ObservableCollection<viewArticle>();
    public ObservableCollection<viewArticle> ModelviewArticleObservableList
    {
        get { return _ModelviewArticleObservableList; }
        set
        {
            _ModelviewArticleObservableList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelviewArticleObservableList");                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps just new up a new observable collection and replace the existing one

Answer (score 4):

Use a property

```
public Int32 ArticleCount
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ModelviewArticleObservableList == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.ModelviewArticleObservableList.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the XAML, bind to this property

```
Text="{Binding ArticleCount, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And don't forget to notify when there is a modification on `ModelviewArticleObservableList`

```
RaisePropertyChange<Int32>(() => this.ArticleCount));
```

Comment: This is a great solution, very clear on what it is doing and easy to maintain.

Comment: Thank you @Xaruth. I'm learning the power of exposed properties in MVVM. 1 question, how are you raising the RaisePropertyChange event with an Int32? I only have the INPC interface implemented taking a string of propertyName. I've updated the question with my property...

Comment: `RaisePropertyChange` method is from Prism (actually, I use my own method, but it  is identical). `RaisePropertyChange<Int32>(() => this.ArticleCount)` is equal to `RaisePropertyChange("ArticleCount")` (wich call the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` handler) but I prefer call with expression that seems clearer.